# How to tell Highcharts to set date on the x axis, and use a range of time (like 1 day)

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to understand the issue here; I have a data file that contains dates for each of my value. When I use it on the x axis; the result is that I will have the x axis split the values evenly, so if a point is at 2:30 2:31 and another at 2:32, the values will be side by side, evenly spaced; while I would expect that the x axis would be split based on the first and last date (like in 2 if there are 2 days, in 3 if there are 3 days and so on)

Instead I would like to have a range based on a hour, or a day, and see how many points fits in that  range. This is the example of how the data is organized:

```
a,b,c,d
1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4
Jun 13 22:30, jun 13 23:02, Jun 13 23:05, Jun 14 1:10
```

I have set the type as datetime in the x axis, and the 3rd line with dates, is assigned to the categories.

EDIT:

Seems that the problem is the date format; I convert successfully the string into date

```
new Date(value)
```

Which returns me the full date format:

Wed Jul 11 -001 17:32:10 GMT-0700 (PDT)

The strange thing is that the tooltip, which I set to display this.x, is showing numbers from 1 to 10, instead than the date. Not sure if this may be the cause why I can't make a graph like this, using my data as in the example above.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/

EDIT 2:
Thanks to Sebastian and Skram for the suggestions, I was able to get to this point:

http://jsfiddle.net/newbiez/AeFp3/3/

Now this is doing almost everything right; except that if I comment out the tickInterval, I will get 4 tick, one point each (the original problem); while if I uncomment it; the chart draw the first date, but not the others

Comment: Try just not setting `categories` at all. From what I remember, you dont need `categories` set to anything when type = `datetime`

Comment: Tried to not copy the sequence in an array and not assign it, commenting out the categories: [],  and finally some results. Now thou it is starting from Jan 1st; and goes in increments 0f 00:00:00:005; altho it divided the chart in intervals, which bring me closer to the solution

Comment: Alrighty - I think your next step is to get your `datetime`s into a format Highcharts will like such as Javascript's native `Date` class. You can do: `new Date("jun 13 23:02")` for your x value or parse out the components and use `new Date` as shown on http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/

Comment: Thanks a lot; will try the first option. Can I just use the new Date in line, or do I have to convert each element of the array that contains the date? edited the main question to show the function that I use to split.

Comment: Tried to do the inline conversion with new Date(value), and it won't fix the problem. I get a uber long date, and when I push these values in the categories; it goes back to 1 value per tick. This is really confusing; not sure why I can't have the date behaving as it does when I don't push them in. Obviously the date is the issue; tried also to set in the xAxis the dateTimeLabelFormats, and it won't format it at all. Not sure what else to try at this point

Comment: can you post a full JSFiddle?

Comment: Create a fiddle of your code ! and share the link to it in your question !

Comment: This is the best that I was able to do...I use the code in one external js file, so make it in a fiddle didn't work. I used the example that Skram posted as base. It doesn't show the data, because I don't know how you call functions or refer to the chart (I use document.ready function and create a chart item in there, instead of the method used in the examples )                       http://jsfiddle.net/newbiez/4JjjC/

Comment: I recoomen you to use develope tools (console) then you will notice errors which you have. See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4JjjC/3/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for fixing the example! Now how do I set it up to have points from the same day in a single tick space? With that sample data I would expect to have 2 points in one tick area, and the other 2 in the other tick.

Comment: Made this right now; this is what I am using on the server. If I comment out the tickInterval, it will draw only the first value.  http://jsfiddle.net/newbiez/AeFp3/3/

Answer (score 1):

So, after a lots of trial by error and suggestions here and there (Thanks Sebastian and Skram), found what is wrong.

1) You need to convert dates: as string they won't work, because Highcharts expect to see dates in milliseconds. In addition to this, you must set xAxis `type: 'datetime'`.

2) While in other cases you can put one set of value in an array, and another in a second array, and place them as categories and series; when you deal with date you need to have a 2D array with (converted)date and related value.

3) You must not assign the data to the categories; otherwise you will spend hours trying to figure out why it won't work. You simply need to add the 2D array in data: and it will just  work™

Hope that this will help others; spent quite a lot of time to figure this out, and thanks to other members that made me get closer to the solution!