# Unable to display x-Axis data of each point in highchart

Tags: angularjs, date, firebase-realtime-database, highcharts

```
$scope.mData = $firebaseArray(aRef.orderByChild('ts').startAt('2018-07-02').limitToLast(31));
        $scope.mData.$loaded().then(function () {
            $scope.chartSeriesYArray03 = [];
            $scope.chartSeriesXArray03 = [];

            $scope.chartSeries = [];

            angular.forEach($scope.mData, function (value) {
                $scope.chartSeriesXArray03.push(moment(value.ts).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss'));
                $scope.chartSeriesYArray03.push(parseFloat(value.ein));
                $scope.chartSeries.push([
                    Date.parse(value.ts), parseFloat(value.ein)
                    //moment(value.ts).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss'), parseFloat(value.ein)
                ]);
            });

            Highcharts.setOptions({
                global: {
                    useUTC: false
                }
            });

            var chart003 = Highcharts.chart('chart03', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Half Hourly Energy Consumption'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Energy (kwh)'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Meter01',
                    data: $scope.chartSeries,
                    crosshair: true
                }]
            });

            $scope.mData.$watch(function (cb) {
                if(cb.event == 'child_added') {
                    angular.forEach($scope.mData, function (value) {
                        if(value.$id === cb.key) {
                            chart003.series[0].addPoint([
                                Date.parse(value.ts),
                                //moment(value.ts).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss'),
                                parseFloat(value.ein)
                            ], true, true);
                            console.log('test7', moment(value.ts).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss'), parseFloat(value.ein));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

[See picture for how the graph turns out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YInaR.png)

[image]

So what I wanted to achieve was to display dynamic data from firebase using highcharts. I have managed to push live data across but met with the error of not having my x-axis values that I also did push into the code. I followed this [How to tell Highcharts to set date on the x axis, and use a range of time (like 1 day)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946474/how-to-tell-highcharts-to-set-date-on-the-x-axis-and-use-a-range-of-time-like) answer and managed to display the date in milliseconds. However, I am now unable to put a value below each bar plot and the date only comes out in intervals as shown in the image. How may I go about 
1) putting all the dates of each data bar right below the bar
2) making sure the bar graph is evenly spaced despite the uneven timing that it is published at
3) convert the date to a DD MM YYYY format after passing it through Date.parse()

Thank you! Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Highstock has support for this by default, this can be toggled by: [`xAxis.ordinal`](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal). Additionally, if you are using highcharts, you need to set `xAxis: {type: 'datetime'}` (this is enabled by default in highstock and is the only option, whereas in highcharts you can have several types of xAxis).

Comment: Hi Ewolden! Thanks for the reply! I tried the xAxis.ordinal but no change to the spacing of the graphs (I think it's because I'm using highcharts not highstock!) also yes thanks I managed to solve the datetime issue with that! Thank you!

Comment: I have also tried to add highstocks.js but am still unable to use xAxis.ordinal

Comment: All you have to do to change from highcharts to highstock (in addition to including https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js) is to change this line: `var chart003 = Highcharts.chart('chart03', {` to `var chart003 = Highcharts.stockChart('chart03', {`